# Calling a function from a .hh file not working

Tags: c++

For this question, i ahve basically four main files, let's call it:

```
Constant.hh 

Constant.cc (where a define the function)

Field.hh

Field.cc (where i call the function)
```

So basically, i have defined a function at the file "Constant.cc" and i am calling it to be used at Field.cc. But when i try to run it on terminal (using make), it returns this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/eRosita.dir/application/src/Field.cc.o: in function "FF::GetFieldValue(double const*, double*) const":
Field.cc:(.text+0xcc): undefined reference for "Constant(int, double)"
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And i am not sure why.

The content inside thes four files are:

### Constant.hh

```
#ifndef Constant_h
#define Constant_h 1

double Constant(int f, double p);

#endif
```

### Constant.cc

```
#include <iostream>

double Constant(int f, double p) {
if (f == 30){
return 3;}
else{
return 0;}
}
```

### Field.hh

```
#ifndef Field_h
#define Field_h 1

class FF : public G4ElectroMagneticField {

    public:
        ~FF();
        virtual void  GetFieldValue(const G4double Point[4], G4double *Bfield ) const override;
        virtual G4bool DoesFieldChangeEnergy() const override;

};
#endif
```

### Field.cc

```
#include "Constant.hh"

FF::~FF(){}

G4bool FF::DoesFieldChangeEnergy() const{
    return true;
}

void FF::GetFieldValue(const G4double Point[4], G4double field[6]) const
     
    double r = sqrt(x*x+y*y);

    double p = 2*pi*r/(400*0.025);
    int f = -20;
    
    double E = Constant(f,p);
  }
```

(OBS: the unecessary part of the code i have just deleted, so that the question get more summarized)

Comment: Is `Constant.cc` being compiled and linked? Seems like it is not.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Not sure what do you mean. Inside the make file?